# How to update a table with the information from another table using only SQL?

Tags: mysql

MySQL  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16, for Win64 (x86_64)

I have two tables:

```
content_table: content_id, content(String), tag_id(int)

tag_table: tag_id(int), tag(String)
```

Now `content_table.tag_id` are all empty.

I want to do such things:

For each record in content_table, I want to find the proper tag_id(only one) and updated the record.tag_id. The tag should be a sub-string of content.

Is there a way to do it only with SQL?
Or I have to use a JDBC or something in another language?

Thanks.

data example:

In content_table, I have these records:

`content_id, content, tag_id
1, "This is a great movie", 0
2, "I bought the car last week", 0
3, "His iPad is a gift from his brother", 0`

In tag_table, I have these records:

`tag_id, tag
1, "movie"
2, "iPad"
3, "car"
4, "phone"
...`

After operation, I want to update content_table to:

`content_id, content, tag_id
1, "This is a great movie", 1
2, "I bought the car last week", 3
3, "His iPad is a gift from his brother", 2`

These records are examples, in fact, there are 10K+ records in content_table and 3k+ records in tag_table.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and/or explain how you match tags to content?

Comment: Can't understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Check out mysql [full text search functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate a two dimensional array say, tagArray, with tag_id, tag from the tag table then iterate over array to substiture id and like variables from the array into the following update sql statement and execute the statement:

String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE content_table SET tag_id ="+tagArray[i][0] + 
" WHERE content LIKE CONCAT('%'," + tagArray[i][1]+", '%')";

Comment: That is good for one or two records, but what should I do if there were 10k+ records in each table?

Comment: Agreed, I would combine Java and this sql command to iterate through records and dynamically populate the update command. So populate an array from the tag table then iterate over array to substiture id and like variables from the array.